# Express.js: Cookie Set but Undefined on First Reques

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, middleware

I'm encountering an issue in my Express.js application where I'm setting a cookie in one middleware function, but it's returning as undefined when trying to access it in a subsequent middleware function on the first request. However, on subsequent requests, the cookie value is accessible as expected.

I've ensured that the cookie-parser middleware is correctly configured and placed before the middleware where I'm trying to access the cookie. The cookie is being set using res.cookie() with appropriate options, and I've verified that the cookie name matches what I'm trying to access.

Interestingly, when I hit the route again, I can retrieve the cookie value without any issues. It seems like the cookie is being set correctly but is not accessible on the first request.

**Course Route**

```
courseRouter.post('/course/create', updateAccessToken, isAuthenticate, authorizedRoles("admin"), createCourse);
```

**updateAccessToken middleware:**

```
res.cookie("access_token", accessToken, accessTokenOptions);
```

**isAuthenticate middleware:**

```
const token = req.cookies.access_token;
console.log(token);
```

I got token **undefined** in first request. But 2nd request, I got the token.

Could someone shed light on why the cookie is not accessible on the first request, but works fine on subsequent requests? Any insights or suggestions on how to debug and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You are accessing the cookie as part of the current _request_ data set (`req`) - but no _new_ request has been made at this point.

Comment: thanks. how can I get this in the same request?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are usually set by `Set-Cookie` header *on response*.

> The Set-Cookie HTTP response header is used to send a cookie from the server to the user agent, so that the user agent can send it back to the server later.
> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)

`req` and `res` are two separate objects for handling incoming request and send out response, what you do to one won't effect another.

When you set the cookie in your `updateAccessToken` middleware, it wouldn't been set by the user agent because you haven't reach the end of request cycle and send a response back. And since this is the very first request, there is no cookie on current `req` object.

Once you send the response back, your user agent would recognise the header and set cookies. On subsequent requests, the user agent can carry that over so `req` object will then have a `cookie` field to read from.